# Google Place Add API Returning Invalid_Request for C# client

Tags: google-maps, dotnet-httpclient

This is my C# code:

```
private async Task<AddPlaceResponse> AddLocation(Place place)
        {
            AddPlaceResponse resp = new AddPlaceResponse();

            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(place), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    string url = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MYKEY");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, contentPost);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var data =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var status = data.Result;
                        resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddPlaceResponse>(status);

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return resp;
        }
```

This is the request Json (place object):

```
{"location":{"lat":"22.5674722","lng":"88.3086388"},"accuracy":50,"name":"Prabartak Sangha","phone_number":"(+91) 8909878909","address":"Sitanath Banerjee Lane","types":["shoe_store"],"website":"https://www.google.co.in","language":"en"}
```

I failed to understand why I am always getting `"Invalid_Request"` as status.

Please help.

Comment: There is no problem with api key as the searchplace method is working perfectly with the same api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check request body of your HTTP POST add request.

As mentioned in [Place Add - Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#status-codes),

> `INVALID_REQUEST` generally indicates that the request contains missing parameters. It will also be returned when attempting to add a place whose name is greater than 255 characters.

As given in [Add a place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#add-place), please note that there are *required parameters* and also have limitation.

- `accuracy`
- `address` - (recommended)
- `language`
- `location` - (required)
- `name` - (required and limited to 255 characters)
- `phone_number` - (recommended)
- `types` - (required)
- `website` - (recommended)

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).